# why is my Gate always denied the request on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-gate

Little help here. I have two models user and post. So i want to restrict a user from editing post's of other users so i used this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
        Gate::define('update-post', function (User $user, Post $post) {
              return $user->id === $post->user_id;
        });
    }
```

In App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php. and in my controller at edit method i use this code:

```
public function edit($id, Post $post, User $user)
    {
       
       if(Gate::allows('update-post', $post)){
          $posts = Post::find($id);
          return view('pages.edit')->with('posts', $posts);
          
       }
       
        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'you cannot edit this post');
    }
```

It works but when i clicked on edit button from the two users account it goes to what i redirdect on the edit controller.

So how can i fix that, please help!!!

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you verified that the authenticated user's ID does match the post's ID? Have you verified that the user and post parameters contain the values you expect in the `Gate` definition?

Comment: does your route definition actually have a parameter for `post` ... if not `$post` is an empty new model (via dependency injection) so it doesn't have a `user_id` attribute